# IPOJO - The factory associated with the component type is invalid (not started or missing handlers)

Tags: java, factory, composite-component, apache-felix, ipojo

I am trying to learn how to use Felix iPOJO API to create components dynamically.

I have a simple bundle with the following files:

1- `HelloService.java` (Contains a Service Interface).

```
/*
 * @author zaid almahmoud
 *
*/
package helloipojo.service;

public interface HelloService
{

    public void sayHello();

}
```

2- Its implementation `HelloServiceImpl.java`:

```
package helloipojo;

import helloipojo.service.HelloService;


public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService{

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {

        System.out.println("Hello iPojo!");

    }


}
```

3- `Activator.java` :

```
package helloipojo;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;


public class Activator implements BundleActivator {


        public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {


            System.out.println("Bundle Started!");


        }
        public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

             context = null;
             System.out.println("Bundle Stopped!");


        }

}
```

4- `MANIFEST.MF` :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloIPojo
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloIPojo
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: helloipojo.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

In my application, I start Felix framework and deploy the following bundles:

```
iPOJO (core)
iPOJO Composite
iPOJO API
```

According to [this](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-ipojo-api.html) source.

Next, I install my bundle, and instantiate the component. Below is my class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.felix.framework.Felix;
import org.apache.felix.framework.util.FelixConstants;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.ComponentInstance;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.MissingHandlerException;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.UnacceptableConfiguration;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.ComponentType;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.PrimitiveComponentType;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.Service;

public class HostApplication
{
    private HostActivator m_activator = null;
    private Felix m_felix = null;


    public HostApplication()
    {
        // Create a configuration property map.
        Map config = new HashMap();
        config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
        // Create host activator;
        m_activator = new HostActivator();
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(m_activator);

        config.put(FelixConstants.SYSTEMBUNDLE_ACTIVATORS_PROP, list);

        try
        {
            // Now create an instance of the framework with
            // our configuration properties.
            m_felix = new Felix(config);
            // Now start Felix instance.
            m_felix.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not create framework: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Register the application's context as an OSGi service!
        BundleContext bundleContext1 = m_felix.getBundleContext();


                System.out.println("6");

                try {

                    //starting ipojo required bundles
                    Bundle coreBundle = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:C:\\Users\\zaid.almahmoud\\Dropbox\\EBTIC\\ADERE\\feasibility-codes\\ipojo\\ipojo-distribution-1.11.0\\bundle\\org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.6.2.jar");
                    coreBundle.start();
                    if(coreBundle.getState()== coreBundle.ACTIVE)
                        System.out.println("Core Bundle is Active!");

                    Bundle apiBundle = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:C:\\Users\\zaid.almahmoud\\Dropbox\\EBTIC\\ADERE\\feasibility-codes\\ipojo\\ipojo-distribution-1.11.0\\bundle\\org.apache.felix.ipojo.api-1.6.0.jar");
                    apiBundle.start();
                    if(apiBundle.getState()== apiBundle.ACTIVE)
                        System.out.println("API Bundle is Active!");


                    Bundle compositeBundle = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:C:\\Users\\zaid.almahmoud\\Dropbox\\EBTIC\\ADERE\\feasibility-codes\\ipojo\\ipojo-distribution-1.11.0\\bundle\\org.apache.felix.ipojo.composite-1.6.0.jar");
                    compositeBundle.start();
                    if(compositeBundle.getState()== compositeBundle.ACTIVE)
                        System.out.println("Composite Bundle is Active!");


//HERE INSTALLING AND STARTING MY BUNDLE!!
Bundle b = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:C:\\Users\\zaid.almahmoud\\Desktop\\plugins\\HelloIPojo_1.0.0.201401211340.jar");
                b.start();

                    try {

                        ComponentType type = new PrimitiveComponentType()
                                .setBundleContext(b.getBundleContext()) 
                                .setComponentTypeName("hello.type") 
                                .setClassName("helloipojo.HelloServiceImpl") 
                                .setImmediate(true); 
                        type.start(); 

                        ComponentInstance instance = type.createInstance();



                    } 

                    catch (UnacceptableConfiguration
                            | MissingHandlerException | ConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } // Create the instance







                    System.out.println("done starting bundles!");


                } catch (BundleException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                    System.out.println("Not done!");
                }



                //shutdownApplication();

    }

    public Bundle[] getInstalledBundles()
    {
        // Use the system bundle activator to gain external
        // access to the set of installed bundles.
        return m_activator.getBundles();
    }

    public void shutdownApplication()
    {
        // Shut down the felix framework when stopping the
        // host application.
        try {
            m_felix.stop();
        } catch (BundleException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            m_felix.waitForStop(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application, it shows the following output (with the error at the end):

```
6
Core Bundle is Active!
API Bundle is Active!
Composite Bundle is Active!
Bundle Started!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The factory associated with the component type is invalid (not started or missing handlers)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.ComponentType.ensureFactory(ComponentType.java:189)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.ComponentType.ensureAndGetFactory(ComponentType.java:177)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.api.ComponentType.createInstance(ComponentType.java:79)
    at HostApplication.<init>(HostApplication.java:109)
    at Embedder.main(Embedder.java:11)
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

**Update 1**

I could see that I am missing 2 handlers. I knew that by adding the following two lines:

```
 System.out.println(type.getFactory().getRequiredHandlers());
 System.out.println(type.getFactory().getMissingHandlers());
```

The output of the above two lines is:

```
[org.apache.felix.ipojo:architecture, org.apache.felix.ipojo:callback]
[org.apache.felix.ipojo:architecture, org.apache.felix.ipojo:callback]
```

I also tried:

`type.getFactory().createComponentInstance(new Properties());`

then I got:

```
org.apache.felix.ipojo.MissingHandlerException: Missing handlers : org.apache.felix.ipojo:architecture org.apache.felix.ipojo:callback
```

I don't know why these handlers are missing. I tried to add them, but could not figure out the right syntax. Any help? Thanks.

**Update 2**

According to Clement in [his](http://apache-felix.18485.x6.nabble.com/Using-iPOJO-API-to-create-components-and-instances-td4881802.html) answer, my bundle should import: `org.apache.felix.ipojo` and `org.apache.felix.ipojo.architecture`

I did that, and now I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.felix.ipojo.HandlerManagerFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.felix.ipojo.HandlerFactory
```

I am getting the error at this line: `type.start();`

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the asynchronous start of iPOJO. When you create your instance, not everything is available.

I’ve several question: Why are you using the iPOJO API to declare your type and instance ? Can’t you just use the annotations ? In that case it will just create everything smoothly.

If you really need / want to use the API, don’t create the instance like you do, but expose an instance declaration: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/ipojo-factory-service.html#deleting-instances. The declaration waits until the factory is valid to create the instance.

Comment: Thanks. My number 1 goal is to be able to create, start, and stop the components dynamically. I don't think this is possible with annotations, is it?

I tried this:

                     InstanceDeclaration declaration = new DefaultInstanceDeclaration(b.getBundleContext(), "my-factory");

It shows no errors, but the author of the link you posted says that you can start and stop the declaration instance. Though, I did not find a start or stop method (declaration.start() showed a syntax error). What's going on?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can update your answer with a code snippet just to show the right syntax.

Comment: Finally, do I have a full access to my bundle services, references, properties using the declaration instance? Can I manipulate those dynamically using that instance? Many Thanks.

Comment: The declaration instance seems weird to me. This is because it doesn't require the implementation class, nor the service interface. How can I possibly invoke a service that is in my bundle using Declaration Instance? I am looking at the API but I couldn't figure out the way.